# "Open Event Log" in SDL Tridion 2013

Tags: 2013

We have just migrated to SDL Tridion 2013. I have noticed that in Administration Toolbar ribbon, "Open Event Log" Logging option is not available.

The below folder/file (which in earlier versions used to be available) is not present on CME server.

http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Popups/EventLog/EventLog.aspx#popup=UID_123

Has it been dropped-off in SDL Tridion 2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This used to open the logging database, which had been deprecated in 2011 and dropped on 2013. Only legacy (COM) elements logged to it since 2009, and most of the .NET processes were logging to the windows event viewer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking through the upgrade documentation [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-507E4678-F930-44DF-97B2-090037A724FE) I don't see the button mentioned, but I can confirm that my 2011 machine includes this button, whilst my 2013 doesn't.

Perhaps this is one of the tools added by the 'Legacy Pack', might be worth checking it out?

It's possible to get to this information by connecting to the machine and viewing the system event log directly on the machine.